# Name the buffer with the current command that runs in the term emulator

Tags: terminal

I know it's weird and I don't know if it's possible but it would be great to have the name of the command I run in the terminal emulator when I use bash or zsh.

At the moment, to launch a new terminal, I do something like `:term zsh` so the buffer is named `term://.//26149:zsh`. Now, I launch a long running command like `docker-compose up app`. I want the buffer to be renamed to something like `term://.//docker-compose up app`. I can do it manually by using `:file` but is there a way to do it automatically?

The main goal is to access it very fast by doing `:b docker`. If you have other tips to do that, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative:

- Do `:b term<tab>`. Assuming you do not have many terminal buffers open. Or `:b term` if you only have 1 instance
- Set a file mark, `mD`, then use `'D` to return
- Use `:file` to name your buffer something you like and will remember. e.g. `:file repl`

Now in theory if you can change the buffer name via `:file` and `b:term_title` is the current program, then you can automatically change the buffer name. Maybe update the buffer name when you leave the buffer. The idea:

```
augroup TermName
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufLeave term://* if len(get(b:, 'term_title', '')) | execute 'file ' . matchstr(expand('<afile>'), 'term://(.{-}//(\d+:)?)?\ze.*') . escape(b:term_title, ' ') | endif
augroup END
```

Note: I do not have NeoVim and I have not tested this in any way.

Comment: it seems to work. I will try a little more before to accept the answer

Comment: It works. I just added a prefix "command://" and add an autocmd for "command://*" to always have the last process.